# A question about sites downtime updates

Tags: python, django, apache

I've a server when I run a Django application but I've a little problem:

when with mercurial I commit and pushing new changes on the server, there's a micro time (like 1 microsec) where the home page is unreachable.

I have apache on the server.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* run multiple instances of the django app (either on the same machine with different ports or on different machines) and use apache to reverse proxy requests to each instance. It can failover to instance B whilst instance A is rebooting. See [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

If the downtime is as short as you say though, it is unlikly to be an issue worth worrying about.

Also note that there are likely to be better (and easier) proxies than Apache. [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) is popular, as is [HAProxy](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://haproxy.1wt.eu/&ei=InsMTpXWEIG2hQfD3dj6DQ&usg=AFQjCNEhlcmdPhu7eXK_0eiiDAwR_tm2Jw).

Answer (score 1):

If you have any significant traffic in time that is measured in microsecond it's probably best to push new changes to your web servers one at a time, and remove the machine from load balancer rotation for the moment you're doing the upgrade there.

Answer (score 0):

When using `apachectl graceful`, you minimize the time the website is unavailable when 'restarting' Apache. All children are 'kindly' requested to restart and get their new configuration when they're not doing anything.

> The USR1 or graceful signal causes the parent process to advise the children to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately if they're not serving anything). The parent re-reads its configuration files and re-opens its log files. As each child dies off the parent replaces it with a child from the new generation of the configuration, which begins serving new requests immediately.

At a heavy-traffic website, you will notice some performance loss, as some children will temporarily not accept new connections. It's my experience, however, that TCP recovers perfectly from this.

Considering that some websites take several minutes or hours to update, that is completely acceptable. If it is a really big issue, you could use a proxy, running multiple instances and updating them one at a time, or update at an off-peak moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're at the point of complaining about a 1/1,000,000th of a second outage, then I suggest the following approach:

Front end load balancers pointing to multiple backend servers.

Remove one backend server from the loadbalancer to ensure no traffic will go to it.

Wait for all traffic that the server was processing has been sent.

Shutdown the webserver on that instance.

Update the django instance on that machine.

Add that instance back to the load balancers.

Repeat for every other server.

This will ensure that the 1/1,000,000th of a second gap is removed.

Answer (score -1):

i think it's normal, since django may be needing to restart its server after your update